# Why say "Peut-être en a-t-il fait de même." instead of "Peut-être il a fait de même."?

Tags: grammaire

I thought inversion was only really used for questions, why would avoir be placed before the subject in a non-interrogative sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the sentence begins with some adverbs such as *peut-être*, *ainsi*, *à peine*, *encore*, etc., you must indeed use a subject/verb inversion as you would do it for an interrogative sentence.

Note that in colloquial, spoken French, you could say *Peut-être qu'il a fait de même* with no inversion.

Answer (score 0):

*Peut-être en a-t-il fait de même.* est plus complet que *Peut-être a-t-il fait de même.*

*en* remplace *que (moi, ...)*

*de même* implique *de même que ...*

Cela suppose donc une suite (*en* remplace cette suite).