# Why is it "un élève a-t-il besoin de ..." here

Tags: grammaire

Here, this sentence:

> Ainsi, en plus du vocabulaire concret qui permet de désigner et de décrire efficacement, un élève a-t-il besoin de maîtriser un vocabulaire abstrait pour structurer sa pensée et manier les idées.

The question is, why is it: "*un élève a-t-il besoin de ...*"

I thought it would be: *un élève a besoin de...*

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't agree with flagging this as a duplicate because the sentence is not a question.

Comment: In some contexts, you can have an inversion in affirmative sentences, for example when a sentence starts with *ainsi*. See here : https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ainsi/1937#difficulte

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Ah, fair enough. Reopened. They should really give mods the ability to vote instead of swing a hammer. Then again, there are a lot of things they should do.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Of course the sentence is not a question, but why would this question [Why say "Peut-être en a-t-il fait de même." instead of "Peut-être il a fait de même."?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/29569/358) not b a duplicate? The accepted answer does specify *ainsi* in the list.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I just don't get it. And yet another duplicate [Pourquoi inverser l'ordre des mots dans « sans doute n’est-ce plus » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/26705/358) that's even older than the other two and the accepted answer is rather comprehensive and mentions *ainsi* and is rather comprehensive, more references, including the one given on the present page.

Comment: Merci beaucoup,

Comment: Thanks, @None -- I'll close with the second one. The one I had picked before was an interrogative, but I didn't see the others.

Comment: @None It as flagged as a duplicate of another question, a basic "how does inversion works in questions". You're absolutely right that it was indeed a duplicate, but of another question

Comment: @None No worries!

Answer (score 1):

In some contexts, you can have an inversion in an affirmative sentence. It happens when the sentence starts with: *à peine ... que, ainsi, aussi, du moins, en vain, encore, non seulement, peut-être, sans doute, toujours...*. It's only used in formal language. More [here](http://www.servicesdedition.com/fr/langue/difficultes/inversion.html).

> À peine était-il entré dans la pièce qu'il ressentit un grand malaise.

> Peut-être était-il confus.

> [Toujours est-il que](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/toujours_est-il_que) sans lui, rien de tout cela ne serait arrivé.

The [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ainsi/1937#difficulte) mentions it only happens when it is *not* followed by a coma. There is one in your sentence, but the whole sub-proposition "*en plus du vocabulaire concret qui permet de désigner et de décrire efficacement*" should be considered as an "optional" addition that doesn't change the structure of the sentence without it:

> Ainsi [...] un élève a-t-il besoin de maîtriser un vocabulaire abstrait pour structurer sa pensée et manier les idées.

In the first link there's an example of correct sentences with and without the comma, with a slight difference in meaning:

> Aussi, elle décida d’aller faire le plein (= en plus d’autre chose).

> Aussi décida-t-elle d’aller faire le plein (= après avoir constaté que le réservoir était vide et qu’il valait mieux aller le faire remplir).

Comment: Merci beaucoup!!!

Answer (score 0):

Soit la phrase n’est pas correcte, soit c’est une interrogation, vous avez raison on devrait plutôt utiliser <<un élève à besoin de >> parce que la phrase citée n’a pas vraiment de sens si c’est une affirmation.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!

Answer (score 0):

Il s'agit d'une inversion spécifique après le mot "Ainsi" en tête de phrase, qui est facultative :

https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_i&page=9opkVN9D2Afc.html

```
Inversion facultative

Après les adverbes et expressions énumérés ci-dessous, l’inversion du sujet est très fréquente, mais pas obligatoire :

    ainsi (signifiant « c’est ainsi que »)
        Ainsi parlait-il.
        Ainsi l’ai-je convaincu de revenir.
        Ainsi va la vie!
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup!!!